I have cors error when I want to use https://tenancyforlaravel.com/ with next
I am trying multitenant app in laravel 11 with nextJS for front  and face this problem
when I want to use
 const response = await axios.post<LoginResponse>(
        "http://test1.localhost:8000/login",
        {
          email,
          password,
        }
      );


it gives me cors error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://test1.localhost:8000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
but when I send request to http://localhost:8000 it works fine

I solved the problem by adding login in route in cors.php
return [
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
| or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
| in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
|
| To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
|
*/

'paths' => ['api/*','login', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,

];
